# Changes not being saved when using Mac Netboot

Tags: macos, boot, mac, netboot

Today I wanted to give NetInstall service a try thats comes with MacOS Server.

I have 2 machines: A (iMac) & B (Mac Mini).

Installed MacOS Server on A. Downloaded Mac Sierra installation from Mac App Store and created a NetBoot image ( Please do not confuse it with Net install OR restore). I created BOOT image. Everything went well, as soon as I selected Mac Sierra Netboot it asked me to create user account and it installed perfectly and created a disk image.

I have 2 options to see network boot options on machine B. Holding down N OR Option key. I can see boot image that I created on Machine A and I can easily boot from it.

Its the perfect setup I wanted as on Machine A, I recently upgraded to SSD and I want to enjoy the speeds of SSD on both machines using this setup.

But, strange thing that comes now is that I created 2 folders on Machine B after Netboot on Sierra and made some settings and installed some Apps, but nothing got saved and got lost when I restarted my boot image. wow!!! What is this hard work for if changes are not saved? Thank you Apple.

Please note I also tried (Diskless operation mode) on the disk settings on Machine A, it created a shadow file (on Machine A) next time I booted the Machine B, the same shadow file which Apple says as Client data. So, when Mac (Machine A), is creating shadow file and storing it, then why it is not applying it next time it boots?

Please, can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the primary point of NetBoot; if this is not what you wanted, then NetBoot is not for you. Essentially, the idea behind NetBoot is that every time the computer starts up, it gets a clean startup image from the server; thus, every computer starting up gets the exact same image every time. Run into trouble? Just reboot! Someone installed malware? Just reboot!

This is really intended for situations like libraries and kiosks, which *should not* have permanent storage. If you want to combine it with something else to get permanent storage (e.g. store your documents on the local HD), you can, but even if you do that you won't be able to install new software on the network image; you have to include it when you build the image. And that's generally an expert-only process.

I should also point out that NetBoot isn't very commonly used, precisely because the situations it works for are rare. Most people want that service for the NetInstall and NetRestore capabilities, which use the basic NetBoot capability to boot an installer image on the clients, install (/restore) software onto the client's disk, and then reboot and run normally. Essentially, it's a software distribution tool, *not* something you use on a continuing basis.

Comment: I do not agree with you on expert-only process for installing new Software. I could easily mount the disk image on Machine A and drag lets say Google Chrome App into it and it worked next time on Netboot. So, basically I want simple Software like this to work every time I Netboot. I can save data on Internal Mac Mini HDD (500GB). I think Apple clearly says that Shadows are created in diskless mode and client changes are saved on disk for next reboot. And, that is why client data location option is there? Please correct me and explain why client data storage option is there?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this, but came up with an alternate solution. I have 3rd Mac (Machine C) and it was so easy to boot it in target disk mode holding down "T" OR reboot from System preferences.

This 3rd Mac also has inbuilt SSD and so I partitioned it and carved out a new empty volume of around 30 GB. And, so using Netinstall (NOT Netboot), I could easily install Sierra from Machine A to target disk of Machine C ON Machine B.

No doubt, I love Macs.